# Limiting votes for users with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I made a very simple forum where the user can sign up, login and make posts. I'm trying to implement a feature where users can like posts, but I'm having a hard time getting it so the user can only like each post once. So far, I have it so the user can click "Like" and it'll increment the "likeCount" field of the post document by 1.

What I've been trying to do is make a separate model just for tracking likes, where it'll take the email of the user and the id of the post they like, and check if the email and id exist in the "Vote" collection. If they do exist, the user is denied. I've been trying to do this using the collection.find() function but I must be doing it wrong because I'm having a lot of trouble. Any help would be much appreciated

The like button in the forum.ejs file:

```
<form action="/forum/<%= newPost.id %>/like?_method=POST" method="POST" class="d-inline">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Like</button>
</form>
```

The voting code:

```
router.post('/forum/:id/like/', async (req,res) =>{ //like post
    const likePost = await Createpost.findById(req.params.id)

    let voteInfo = new Vote({
        voteEmail: req.user.email,
        votePost: likePost.id,
    });

    if (Vote.find(req.user.email && likePost.id)){
        req.flash('error_msg', 'You already voted!')
        res.redirect ('/forum')
    }
    else{
    Createpost.updateOne({_id: likePost}, {$inc: {likeCount:1}}, 
        function (err, user){
        if (err) return next(err);
        User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            voteInfo = voteInfo.save()
            req.flash('success_msg', 'Post liked!')
            return res.redirect('/forum'), {
            }
        });
            })
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with how you are querying the Vote model

```
let votes = await Vote.find({ voteEmail: req.user.email ,  votePost : likePost.id});
if(votes.length>0){


}
```

[Mongoose.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Comment: Suggest you to keep null checks before doing something like likePost.id unless you are absolutely sure if likePost is not null.